# \graphicspath : Images with duplicate filenames, different folder locations

Tags: graphics, folders

If I have a figure folder hierarchy such as:

./Figures/A/a.pdf
./Figures/A/b.pdf
./Figures/A/c.pdf

./Figures/B/a.pdf
./Figures/B/b.pdf
./Figures/B/c.pdf

How can I point `B/a.pdf` when `A/a.pdf` precedes it,
without needing to change the file name?

Comment: you need to change the graphicspath or use `\includegraphics{Figures/B/a.pdf]`

Comment: is there any method to merely extend the filename to include the first path back only? as in `\includegraphics{B/a.pdf}`. My figures would be many folders deep and sometimes I just want to be able to add one added above directory path to differentiate between those with the same file name in different directories.

Comment: B/a.pdf will work if Figures is in your search path (by the way adding comments to old questions are unlikely to be seen, you were lucky this time as it pinged me as the only person to have commented)

Comment: @DavidCarlisle Your reputation precedes you ; j (I checked it before posting; I thought you might be on sooner or later.)  These are alternative answers to Heiko - why not post them as an answer for an upvote as well?

Comment: it's really same as Heiko's anwser he doesn't hav e absolute paths either `/usr/local/foo/bar.png` would be different but `a.pdf`, `A/a.pdf`, `Figures/A/a.pdf` are all more or less handled the same way as a local name which is appended to each directory in the search path

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The file name can be specified with the path:

```
\includegraphics{Figures/A/a.pdf}
\includegraphics{Figures/B/a.pdf}
```

Or the graphics path can be set by:

```
\graphicspath{{Figures/A/}}
\includegraphics{a}% Figures/A/a.pdf
\includegraphics{b}% Figures/A/b.pdf
...
\graphicspath{{Figures/B/}}
\includegraphics{a}% Figures/B/a.pdf
\includegraphics{b}% Figures/B/b.pdf
```

Comment: For the latter method, could you add script to save the original universal path for easy swapping between the global and the custom path?

Comment: @kando Just put it inside a group, after the group end, the original path is restored automatically.

Comment: this didn't work for includesvg

Comment: @con The documentation of package [svg](https://www.ctan.org/pkg/svg) says otherwise: (a) it provides `\svgpath` and (b) the paths of `\graphicspath` are also searched. It recommends not to use non-ASCII characters, spaces and quotes.