# includesvg for files with the same name in different folders/directories

Tags: graphics, svg, folders

I have two separate files, in different folders/directories, but with the same file name.

```
\begin{figure}[htp]
\includesvg[width = \textwidth]{/home/con/identify.target/A/svg/msa.svg}
\caption{}
\label{fig:1}
\end{figure} \FloatBarrier
\begin{figure}[htp]
\includesvg[width = \textwidth]{/home/con/identify.target/B/svg/msa.svg}
\caption{}
\label{fig:2}
\end{figure} \FloatBarrier
```

which is what I did originally, which doesn't work, as both images show identically

I have tried the solution from:
[\graphicspath : Images with duplicate filenames, different folder locations](https://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/309486/graphicspath-images-with-duplicate-filenames-different-folder-locations)

which makes my code into

```
    \graphicspath{{/home/con/identify.target/A/}}
    \begin{figure}[htp]
    \includesvg[width = \textwidth]{msa.svg}
    \caption{}
    \label{fig:1}
    \end{figure} \FloatBarrier
\graphicspath{{/home/con/identify.target/B/}}
    \begin{figure}[htp]
    \includesvg[width = \textwidth]{msa.svg}
    \caption{}
    \label{fig:2}
    \end{figure} \FloatBarrier
```

which unfortunately produces the same result, the images are still treated identically

I have also tried `extractpath` and `extractname` from the manual https://mirror.math.princeton.edu/pub/CTAN/graphics/svg/doc/svg.pdf

Renaming the files should work,but I don't want to have to rename thousands of files.

Comment: Did you copy/past the same path, in your example code? Looks the same.

Comment: @rallg that's a typo, when I made the minimum working example. Sorry about that, I've corrected it

Comment: I cannot answer the question, but I notice that there seems to be a difference in your code and the code in your linked answer: Your code uses absolute path, but the other code uses relative path to subfolder. Is that relevant, or not?

Comment: @rallg I don't think that's relevant, but https://github.com/mrpiggi/svg/issues/11 provides a workaround for this problem

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This is a (unfortunately long standing) known issue. See https://github.com/mrpiggi/svg/issues/11. As a workaround, you should use `inkscapepath=svgsubdir`.